# Possibility of implementing node.js using PHP interpreter in place of JavaScript v8?

Tags: php, rest, soap, node.js

I have a command line application developed in PHP that currently utilizes files and DB content for input.  I have need for more universal interoperability and have stumbled upon Node.js.  I see that it would allow me to very quickly create a RESTful or SOAP interface that would be scalable on the front end with minimal effort.

Knowing it is written in C and uses the JavaScript V8 I was wondering if any thought by anyone has been put into doing a parallel implementation of node.js as say, node.php?  PHP developers would gain the wonders of this framework and of course I could take immediate advantage with limited changes to my current code base.

What might be the feasibility, viability and potential challenges to such an implementation?  How rooted in the JavaScript engine within Node.js and could it easily be replaced with a PHP engine?

Comment: PHP as lots of blocking standard API. If you use a single blocking PHP function your entire node.php server crashes. There is just no advantage to doing it in PHP

Comment: @Raynos: Why would it crash? I assume it will just block on the function being called?

Comment: @AlixAxel crash is the wrong word. It blocks. If node blocks that's a huge bottleneck. It "crashes" your scalability, it "crashes" the very concept of scalability through async IO.

Comment: @Raynos: node.js blocks on some stuff too (like `require`s) and that doesn't seem to be a bottleneck at all.

Comment: @AlixAxel that's because all that blocking is done before `http.createServer`. When your not dealing requests it's fine to block. Basically you can block on start up, but once you boot up the HTTP server you _must not_ block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who have contributed in great depth to this topic :)

To sum up as I understand from all the above discussions:

1.) The lack of event driven behavior within PHP makes it a challenge to leverage it in an async. non-blocking IO pattern that is utilized within Node.js

2.) If it were possible to support events efficiently within PHP, the act of implementing something like a "Node.php" is more than a rip and replace of the engine, since much of the basic functionality is actually JavaScript written on top of the C code (such as http, console, log, net stream, etc.)

3.) The lack of first-class functions makes it a challenge to provide the same syntax and approach.

NOTE: I used the term syntax because I know there is a callback syntax within PHP and I would think that could be used instead of first-class functions but would not flow as elegantly.

4.) Performance characteristics of JavaScript v8 are proving substantially more performant than PHP.

Thanks again for all the great responses!  My choice of using PHP at the time of prototyping was purely expediences and economics.  If I had been made away of Node.js when the project was started I would have considered JS from the beginning.  As I am now moving from prototype to production I must decide upon porting to something like Node.js, pure C++ or something like Erlang or Scala.  A lot more questions and decisions ahead of me :P

Comment: Having done some more research into Node.js, JavaScript, PHP and what not I have discovered PHPDaemon...It looks like it is a similar implementation of a web server which in theory implement async. loop.  I have only just began to delve deeper but found a few useful links (readable thanks to translate.google.com :P )

http://phpdaemon.net/

http://groups.google.com/group/phpdaemon

http://habrahabr.ru/company/ontico/blog/116211/

Answer (score 5):

If all you're interested in is to "very quickly create a RESTful or SOAP interface" in PHP, then you may be looking in the wrong direction.

Rather than looking for a reimplementation of V8 + node.js in PHP, there are numerous existing PHP frameworks out there that offer similar abstractions. See: http://www.noupe.com/php/discussing-php-frameworks.html.

Comment: -1, No PHP framework that I know of has node.js-like features.

Comment: I believe there is nothing wrong with my questions as I want to understand the possibilities and limiting factors that may prevent the possibility of such an implementation...As an aside, if there are currently similar approaches that can scale and perform like Node.js but leverage PHP code I am happy to hear about those as well :)

Comment: @Alix, perhaps you are right, but it depends on what you mean by "node.js-like features". I understand where you're coming from, but I'm simply suggesting that the OP seems to only want to "very quickly create a RESTful or SOAP interface" - which many PHP frameworks already allow.

Comment: @j_p there is nothing wrong with your question :) If all you're interested in is entertaining the idea of a node.js styled library in PHP, then please disregard my answer. However, PHP does allow you to quickly build web applications with various frameworks, in case you haven't seen those.

Comment: Sorry then, I misinterpreted your point and I reversed my vote.

Answer (score 4):

I've also entertained a similar idea, however my conclusions were not the best:

- node.js seems to be much faster (+10x) than PHP in my benchmarks (simple loops)
- implementing a PHP based web server can be done (and [some](http://nanoserv.si.kz/) [projects](http://nanoweb.si.kz/) [already](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/builtinwebserver) exist)
- PHP isn't non-blocking by default (although it can be with [streams](http://thethoughtlab.blogspot.com/2007/04/non-blocking-io-with-php-mio.html) and extensions like [libevent](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.libevent.php))

My conclusion was: if you get libevent to work properlly with file handles / streams and code some wrappers around it you can have something that is very similar to node.js, just not in terms of performance. Also, one other important conclusion: when it comes to the garbage collector, PHP is not that great so it might not be a good idea to have a PHP script running forever as an HTTP deamon.

Comment: In regards to GC I would say PHP sucks, but as I have resolved much of these issues because I avoid releasing memory to the stack and recycle, which is most important to keeping CPU down (otherwise process spends a lot of time asking OS for alloc).

Comment: I have seen benchmarks going both ways depending, but I believe performance can only be compared when the two are both evented and compared, so that sound fair?

I have considered the idea of libevent and will investigate more along these lines (why not also consider libev, which is utilized by Node.js?)

Comment: I am not so much interested in the web server being implemented in PHP but a Node like server that can execute PHP upon events.  I would think the Node.js C base code could be leveraged along with PHP interpreter.  I see also that many of the extensions provided with Node is written as JS so those types of things would have to be ported as we.

So the big question is, if the event issue would be resolved would it be possible and viable?

Comment: @j_p: I think so, why not? The performance would be worst of course but PHP performance should evolve for the better in the coming versions. But I don't quite get your question: you can alreay execute PHP upon node.js trigered events, either via CLI or any other SAPI.

Comment: @j_p It is viable but "PHP isn't non-blocking by default". You have to re-write _all_ your code to be non-blocking. You cannot port existing PHP code to run on node.PHP, there would be no point / gain.

Comment: @Raynos: Why rewrite all code? If I was going down this road I would just start by rewriting expensive operations related to disk and network IO, and this could be done without much effort. I don't really think you gain much from implementing non-blocking IO for `strtolower()` and friends.

Comment: @AlixAxel Ok all was an over statement. most of the PHP I've been exposed would need a serious re-write to handle non blocking IO.

Answer (score 1):

the biggest challenge i see is that node.js uses event based architecture of v8 engine, and php does not.

Comment: PHP has the libevent extension too.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it before, but you may try http://nanoweb.si.kz/

Also, other people have suggested that this will be built into php:
https://wiki.php.net/rfc/builtinwebserver

Answer (score 0):

PHP already comes with a command line interpreter (CLI), why would there be something else? Node.js cannot be something else, Javascript is not PHP; they do not share the same construct, they do not shsare the same paradigm, and Node.js fills the gap in having Javascript on the server side as well as on the client side... which gap does not exist with PHP.

But are you referring to having PHP listening to HTTP requests and all, like Node.js? In that caase, this will not work well like Node.js. You can still find some projects like what [Arend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247425/possibility-of-implementing-node-js-using-php-interpreter-in-place-of-javascript/6247463#6247463)'s answer is suggesting, or using some other PHP classes/frameworks listening to HTTP connections and handle them... but the project will not pick up. IMO.

Comment: Yes, it is finding a the simplest and quickest way to implement a REST/SOAP interface on top of my PHP process.  I need a web scale architecture that can provide appropriate WS input for my back end server processing.  It is about gaining the ease of Node.js along with its scalable performance, but leveraging PHP language.  I am trying to avoid porting from PHP for as long as possible but gaining functionality on the cheap.

Comment: My goal of is to provide the simples, most cost effective and scalable stack to deploy my logic.  The application performs very well against files and database input at the command line and uses a number of scalable back end database options.  Its next evolution is to have a Web Service like interface so that it can integrate easily into customers' workflow with minimal code effort on their part.  Thus I am looking at Node.js for implementing a RESTful interface that leverages my current code base.  I am interested in the question above, but open to ideas to solve this challenge as well :)

Comment: @j_p You cannot avoid porting. You have to port your PHP to non-blocking PHP or non-blocking JS. This is a huge change. If you do not do then then it will _NOT_ scale.

Comment: @j_p, what makes you think that your current PHP command line application will still perform the same deserving HTTP requests? Also, why not just having a standard Apache+PHP+etc. installation and simply "add" a functionality to deserving requests that way? Because you *can* have a PHP command line application running at the same time as Apache on the same server and simply synchronize both with various methods (i.e. . What you're asking is even more trouble down the road than using a solution that is actually made for what you need.

Comment: @j_p, Raynos is right about that; you will need to port your PHP to non-blocking PHP if it's not already done so, as simply waiting for an incoming connection from a client will block your application. Use the proper tool for the proper job. IMO, if you want a good scalable, command line web stack, take a look at Play! framework. For enterprise solutions, to me Java is more scalable than PHP.

Comment: @YanickRochon Erlang is more scalable then Java ;)

Comment: @Raynos, I've only heard of that language before, finally just took a look at it this morning, and I just dislike the syntax. I respect the ones who does, but I find the C-syntax more to m y likings. I guess it's a matter of taste. Regardless, I was not questioning which language is fastest compared to PHP. And in any case, I will prefer using a technology with a bigger community base and documentation. In terms of cost effectiveness, often unfortunately, speed plays only but a small role in the choice of a technology.

Comment: @YanickRochon I was just commenting on "Java is more scalable than PHP". I don't think you choose Java because it's more scalable. There are plenty of reasons to prefer Java over PHP (or erlang, or node.js). But if you want to recommend a language because its scalable then that would be erlang. Erlang scales massively out of the box, it's a language build from the ground up to make massive concurrency really really easy. All in all, unless scalability is critical I wouldn't actually recommend erlang for enterprise.

Comment: @Raynor, thank you for the precision. I agree on that, then :)

Comment: This question has spawned a number of different topics, but I appreciate them all and believe each has its relevance to the current question...If the question of scalable languages is being address, how might Scala compare to Node.js in terms of potential scaling, ease of use and maintainability?  If porting is on the table, it seems to have more support and longevity than Node.js at present.